# How to/Can i increase the amount of options of a folder in the context menu (right click menu on files/folders/directories) on windows

Tags: windows, registry

Please look at this picture (shows a right click menu of a file):

[image]

You see that there are these files(will be my programs later) with the number(its the name of the files) 3, 12, 1, 345... If you count it, you will see that its exactly 16 files. I tried to add more, but it is limited (even if i make another subfolder (so the arrow)), it will stay at 16 or even become less, by adding one subfolder, it will only be 15 options, it reduces the size of the first subfolder if i add a new one, so that it stays at 16 MAX. Is there any way, to increase the amount of these files of  this subfolder of "MYPROGRAMS"?

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: How is your menu implemented? Registry only? IExplorerCommand? IContextMenu?

Comment: Yes only in the registry, so in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MYPROGRAMS. I plan to implement it with python soon. But this is just by hand.

Comment: Submenu something? There are two registry methods, it would be helpful if you had posted the registry information. Goodbye...